# check if data exists before insert into sqlite database for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite, insert

I want to do insert data into sqlite..While inserting i m getting duplications in my code..i saw the questions related to it and i m getting clear about that..anyone just help me with this code to check data is present before insert into database...

```
- (IBAction)AddtoFavourites:(id)sender {
    sqlite3 *database;
    dbName=@"dataTable.sqlite";
    NSArray *documentpath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentdir=[documentpath objectAtIndex:0];
    dbPath=[documentdir stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];
    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK){
//I want to check data it exists already into database....
       NSString *sqlStatement=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into Persons(PersonName,CompanyName,ImgUrl)values(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",model.personName,model.companyName,model.imgurl];
            const char *insertSQL=[sqlStatement UTF8String];
        char *errMsg;
        sqlite3_exec(database, insertSQL, NULL,NULL,&errMsg);
        NSLog(@"Add to Favourites");        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use select query for any of column as:

```
    const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT PersonName FROM Persons";
```

i guess you would have assigned sqlStatement into compiledStatement

```
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            // Read the data from the result row
            NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];


            [dataArray addObject:aName];
            NSLog(@"%@",aName);
 }
```

Put a check on this

Comment: if your newly PersonName is equal to aName then don't insert

Comment: i found the answer...thanks for you..i used UNIQUE for personName in my sqlite database and used insert or ignore query statement instead of query statement...

Comment: 2 corrects from myself for questions and answers both from you :p